# Problems with importing native C .dll in C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dllimport

I'm trying to import a native DLL (written in C) in my C# project in visual studio. I've tried several ways but still get the same expeption (System.DllNotFoundException).

I've tried to import as follows:

```
#region P/Invoke

[DllImport("GetRotate.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern IntPtr GetRotoTranslateImage([MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String path, int x, int y, int translationX, int translationY, float rotAngle);

#endregion // P/Invoke
```

What's wrong? Why it is not able to find the dll?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough information is provided. What is the `C` header for the function, and where is the .dll file in relation to the C# project.

Comment: Is the dll in the bin folder?  Does the DLL actually export the function ?

Comment: Is it in the right bin folder.  Make sure the dll is in the Release/Debug folder that you are using.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about it.

Comment: How can I know what is the C header for the function? And how can I make the DLL actually to export the function?

Comment: There is a Microsoft utility called `dumpbin /exports` that can check if the function is exported, or use `depends.exe` to graphically see the exports.

Comment: These comments are off the mark. The error is DllNotFoundException. Either the dll cannot be found, or one of its dependencies cannot be found.

Comment: Maybe this DLL has some dependencies that aren't registered or aren't in the same folder as your application.

Comment: @jingmiao you don't register dependencies for native DLLs. They are located using dll search path or SxS.

Comment: And how can I check which are the dependencies of this DLL? I have to find them and put in the correct path, right?